# Help with unit vector problem.

Tags: calculus, vectors

I am trying to solve this problem: Find two unit vectors that make an angle of 60° with
v = 4i + 3j. (Round your answers to four decimal places.)

I have identified that I need to do systems of equations to solve this, but no matter what I find it's wrong.

Please help :(

Comment: What's the definition of the angle between two vectors? (Use it.)

Comment: You certainly do not need systems of equations. Work with angles and basic trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

To do this we will use that the cosine of the angle between two vectors is:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{a\cdot b}{|a||b|}$$
where $a,b$ are vectors. We first calculate the norm (length) of $v=4i+3j$ which is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$ and the cosine of 60 degrees which is  $1/2$. We are looking for vectors $u_1,u_2$ such that $|u_1|=1$, $|u_2|=1$, and which satisfy
$$.5 = \frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}=\frac{u\cdot v}{5}\qquad 2.5=u\cdot v$$
with the same for $u_2$.

Expanding the definition of the dot product, and letting $u=ai+bj$, we have
$$2.5=3a+4b$$ and we want $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$.

You should be able to use a calculator to solve this system of equations. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Use polar form and consider rotating given unitized vector by $60^{\circ}$ both ways.

$$ (A,B)=~e^{i \tan^{-1} \frac{3}{4}}\cdot e^{\pm i \frac{\pi} {3}}$$

Convert to real form and its decimal equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rotation matrices
$$
R_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{\frac{π}{3}} & -\sin{\frac{π}{3}} \\
\sin{\frac{π}{3}} & \cos{\frac{π}{3}}
\end{pmatrix}\\
R_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{\frac{π}{3}} & \sin{\frac{π}{3}} \\
-\sin{\frac{π}{3}} & \cos{\frac{π}{3}}
\end{pmatrix}\\
$$
which rotates a vector $60^\circ$ counter-clockwise and clockwise respectively.

Let $\vec{v}=4\hat{i}+3\hat{j}$. Then the required unit vectors are:
$$
\hat{u_1}=\frac{R_1\vec{v}}{\left|R_1\vec{v}\right|}\\
\hat{u_2}=\frac{R_2\vec{v}}{\left|R_2\vec{v}\right|}
$$